# Why can we assume WLOG that $a+b+c=3$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be reals $ >0$ prove that $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b-c)^2}{(a+b)^2+c^2}\ge \frac{3}{5}$$

In my textbook the author said that we can assume WLOG that $a+b+c=3$. But why is that?

Comment: Note that your expression is homogeneous.  That is, replacing $(a,b,c)$ by $(\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c)$ for a nonzero constant $\lambda$ does not change the sum.  Hence we can make $a+b+c$ whatever we want (except $0$) without loss of generality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To flesh out the comments:  Letting $F(a,b,c)$ denote your sum, we remark that $F$ is scale invariant.  That is to say, $\lambda>0$ implies that $$F(a,b,c)=F(\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c)$$.

Thus, whatever $(a,b,c)$ you have selected can be scaled to get whatever (positive) sum you like.  In particular, you can scale by $\lambda = \frac {3}{a+b+c}$ to ensure that the sum is $3$.

Comment: So I can put any arbitrary condition on $a,b,c$ as long as the sum is homogeneous? Like $abc=1$?

Comment: Well, "arbitrary condition" is pretty broad.  You can certainly get $abc=1$...just scale by $\lambda = \frac 3{\sqrt[3] {abc}}$.